# Add blur effect to navigation scroll bar

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am trying to implement a navbar that has a blur effect when scrolling.
This works, but when I refresh the page, the scrollbar stays in the same position and I don't get any result from `window.pageYOffset`. The result of this is that I have a transparent navigation bar.

I'm also using TailwindCSS, but I think this doesn't matter.

Code example:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

const Navigation: React.FC = () => {
  const [top, setTop] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const scrollHandler = () => {
      window.pageYOffset > 20 ? setTop(false) : setTop(true)
    };
    window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollHandler);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', scrollHandler);
    }
  }, [top]);

  return (
    <header className={`fixed w-full z-30 ${!top && 'bg-white dark:bg-black bg-opacity-80 dark:bg-opacity-80 backdrop-blur dark:backdrop-blur'}`}>
    </header>
  );
};

export default Navigation
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to explicitly call `scrollHandler()` inside the `useEffect` if you want the navbar to keep its blurred state when the page is refreshed.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const scrollHandler = () => {
        setTop(window.pageYOffset <= 20)
    };
    window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollHandler);
    
    // Explicit call so that the navbar gets blurred when component mounts 
    scrollHandler(); 
    
    return () => {
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', scrollHandler);
    }
}, []);
```

You can also remove `top` from the `useEffect`'s dependencies array, you only need it to run when the component is mounted.